# Naming: How do you call an interface that allows to retrieve items?

Tags: interfaces, naming

Let's say a client need to get a list of products from somewhere. He does not care if that list comes from a cache, from a remote database, from a local database, from the resources or from the remote database that only returns item newer than 2 days. So I'd like to interface that behavior. How do I name it? I am missing a word here...

- Storage?
- Source? (works well as UpdatedProductsSource)
- Repository?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Your interface should be named with an adjective that describes the behavior, or a noun to describe what it is.  Is it simply a ProductList?  Or is it some sort of UniversalGenericList?  Normally things like a ProductList are already indifferent to their data source; they don't care where they come from.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for ProductProvider. That leaves the way of providing unspecified, it just says it gives you the products (either downloaded, created, stolen or paid for).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would have some logic deciding what actual *"however you decide to call it"* to use. So, "a client need to get a list of products from somewhere". Well, give it a "**List**". The client does not know from where the "List" comes from, it just knows that it recieves a "List".

However, if we are talking about an object from where you can pull entities or pull lists of entities then we need another name... perhaps an "**Iterator**"?

---

Now, perhaps you want to abstract from where you get the "List" or the "Iterator". In that case, I would argue that it is a "**Database Connection**" (note: database does not imply relational, nor persistent).

However, you could be thinking of an "**Adapter**", that is an object that converts an inconvenient interface into one easier to use. In this case, it is converting the inconvenient interface of the actual data source to something you can use without worrying about it. For instance, if an application can work with different database engines, it will have an adapter for each one.

---

From the words you have, I would call it "**Source**". By making analogy with "DataSource", as an object from where the client code can retrieve entities without worrying for where they actually come.

About the other words you have, "**Storage**" would suggest that you can store there. And for "**Reposity**" I would expect a reperesentation of the place where the data is stored. I would expect it to have information about that place.

Answer (score 0):

If your interface defines a way of retrieving lists of products and getting detailed information about those products then I would say it is an `IProductCatalog`